# "Linking ..\SOURCE\MERGEEXE.EXE:" error

Tags: c++, mergesort, turbo-c++, linker-errors

I found a code for merge sort algorithm that measures the execution time but when I run it, the program won't show up and "Linking ..\SOURCE\MERGEEXE.EXE:" is in the Message panel. Which part of the code is wrong?

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <time.h>

void mergesort(int[], int, int);
void merge(int[], int, int, int);
void mergesort(int a[], int low, int high)
{
    int mid;
    if (low < high) {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        mergesort(a, low, mid);
        mergesort(a, mid + 1, high);
        merge(a, low, high, mid);
    }
}

void merge(int a[], int low, int high, int mid)
{
    int i, j, k, c[50];
    i = low;
    j = mid + 1;
    k = low;
    while ((i <= mid) && (j <= high)) {
        if (a[i] < a[j]) {
            c[k] = a[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }
        else {
            c[k] = a[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    while (i <= mid) {
        c[k] = a[i];
        k++;
        i++;
    }
    while (j <= high) {
        c[k] = a[j];
        k++;
        j++;
    }
    for (i = low; i < k; i++) {
        a[i] = c[i];
    }
}

int main()
{
    int randNum[100];
    clock_t sTime;
    srand((unsigned)clock());

    cout << "Start generating random numbers..." << endl;
    for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
        randNum[index] = (rand() % 1000) + 1;
    }

    sTime = clock();
    mergesort(randNum, 0, 99);
    // delay the program by 0.05 second
    clock_t cWait = clock();

    cout << "Total CPU time used: " << (double)(clock() - sTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Does a trivial "hello world" program "show up"?

Comment: Include proper headers in your code.

Comment: Why is your program formatted in this strange way?

Comment: ***Which part of the code is wrong?*** If your program is not building your compiler will tell you why.

Comment: ***#include <iostream.h>*** Is this turboc++?

Comment: @drescherjm obviously sir it is turbo c++

Comment: Try disabling your antivirus software especially if you use aVast.

Answer (score 1):

Your **c** array is of size 50 whereas you are passing 100 random numbers to the function, hence the segmentation fault. Increase the size of your **c** array and it should work fine.

Comment: i've changed the c array but i'm still getting the same linking error

Comment: What is the error now? Can you modify your question to the current state of your program?

Comment: i still get the same"Linking ..\SOURCE\MERGEEXE.EXE:" and "Compiling ..\SOURCE\MERGEEXE.EXE:" in the message panel. There's no warning that shows up that means there's no error in the code

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure, what compiler does the source of this code using. Trying with DEV C++ 5.1 and adjusting some places of code here is the answer for compilation (though I do not guarantee the expected output.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

void mergesort(int[], int, int);
void merge(int[], int, int, int);
void mergesort(int a[], int low, int high)
{
    int mid;
    if (low < high) {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        mergesort(a, low, mid);
        mergesort(a, mid + 1, high);
        merge(a, low, high, mid);
    }
}

void merge(int a[], int low, int high, int mid)
{
    int i, j, k, c[50];
    i = low;
    j = mid + 1;
    k = low;
    while ((i <= mid) && (j <= high)) {
        if (a[i] < a[j]) {
            c[k] = a[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }
        else {
            c[k] = a[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    while (i <= mid) {
        c[k] = a[i];
        k++;
        i++;
    }
    while (j <= high) {
        c[k] = a[j];
        k++;
        j++;
    }
    for (i = low; i < k; i++) {
        a[i] = c[i];
    }
}

int main()
{
    int randNum[100];
    clock_t sTime;
    //srand((unsigned)clock(NULL));
    srand (time(NULL));

    cout << "Start generating random numbers..." << endl;
    for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
        randNum[index] = (rand() % 1000) + 1;
    }

    sTime = clock();
    mergesort(randNum, 0, 99);
    // delay the program by 0.05 second
    clock_t cWait = clock();

    cout << "Total CPU time used: " << (double)(clock() - sTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds" << endl;
}
```